# Insert using Bulk API throws error MISSING_ARGUMENT:fiedXXX__c not specified:--

Tags: rest-api, data-loader, bulk-api, bulkification, insert

An external system is using bulk api to insert records in Salesforce. Salesforce throws an error saying -

> `MISSING_ARGUMENT:fiedXXX__c` not specified:-- where XXX is external Id of Parent of the records that is being inserted.

I did some research online and found this article related to this - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4SJAA0

The external system is inserting with parent's external id as #N/A. Is there any solution to this ?

The article mention no fix and ask to use Synchronous API - REST API? Is there any other work around for this using Bulk API?

Answer (score -1):

No fix yet, maybe in another few years...

What we end up doing is 2 different bulk jobs, one with all the records that have that field filled in, and a second with that field omitted.